# Attempting to input a value into a cell based on the day but have it skip every other day

Tags: google-sheets

- Column A holds dates using `=today()` and `=today()+1`
- Column B tells me what that day is using `=text(A(#),"dddd"`
- Column C uses `=if(C2="Thursday",sum(Cell),0)`

This gives me the value of the cell every time Thursday is in column B however I would like it to skip every other Thursday. It's for a budget sheet and I'd like a way for my paychecks to be automatically added into the available balance when payday comes in.

Answer (score 0):

Use `if()` in an `arrayformula()` wrapper. Put this formula in row `2` of a free column:

```
=arrayformula( 
  if( 
    (B2:B = "Thursday") 
    *
    iseven(row(B2:B)), 

    sum(F1:G1), 

    iferror(1/0) 
  ) 
)
```